# Can't compile code with semaphore under Solaris?

Tags: c, solaris, linker-errors, semaphore, build-error

I have written some code which compiles fine under linux but on Solaris I am given some compiling errors. I use `gcc test_compile.c -o tes -pthreads` to compile.

```
#include <semaphore.h>

int main(){
    sem_t semaphore;
    sem_init(&semaphore, 0, 0);
    return 0;
}
```

Gives me

```
itchy:~/edu/sysprog> gcc test_compile.c -o tes -pthreads
Undefined                       first referenced
 symbol                             in file
sem_init                            /var/tmp//ccUiSK6A.o
ld: fatal: Symbol referencing errors. No output written to tes
```

I am not sure what's going on. I tryied replacing `sem_init` with `sema_init` and it compiles(saw that somewhere online). However that would mean that I must go through my whole code and replace sem with sema. Isn't there a simpler solution? And what does it really mean?

Comment: You are getting a build-time error, but it is not a compiler error.  Unfortunately, the word "compile" has been used to mean "build an executable", but the two are not the same.  Your problem is with the linker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to link with the realtime extensions library `librt`:

```
gcc test_compile.c -o tes -lrt -pthreads
```

This is documented in the man page for `sem_init(3RT)`:

```
SYNOPSIS
     cc [ flag... ] file... -lrt [ library... ]
     #include <semaphore.h>

     int sem_init(sem_t *sem, int pshared, unsigned int value);
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is true.  [This manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sem_init) seems to indicate you need to link with `pthreads` or `lrt`.  Linking with pthreads makes the most sense (imo).

Comment: You link to a Linux man-page.

I quoted the Solaris man page above and I tested it on Solaris 10. You're right in the sense that you don't _need_ `-pthreads`  to enable `sem_init` on Solaris but at the same time it shouldn't do any harm (binary larger by 24 bytes!).

Comment: So is it `-pthreads` or `-lpthreads`? Sorry I don't have environment to test it yet.

Comment: `-pthreads` for old versions of `gcc`, `-lpthreads` on newer versions

Answer (score 2):

Before all of this, I'd first make sure you're linking correctly.  It seems like compiled fine, but failed at the linking step.  So first make sure you actually have `semaphore.h` and that it includes `sem_init(...)`.  If you do, and my guess is that you do, check your compile command.  If that is your compile command in your question, try adding `-lpthread` to your compile line to link in the posix thread library.

---

So you should double check that sema does what you want, since they're different libraries -- `sem` is from the POSIX `pthreads` library and `sema` is from the solaris `thread` library.  ([See this also](http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/C/node29.html)) But if they're code compatible, and if you're looking for cross-platform compatible code, you'd probably want to do something like create simple wrapper functions and then conditionally include it.

Your wrapper functions would be really simple, accept the same types and return the same type, e.g.

```
ret_type sem_init(argtype arg1, argtype arg2, argtype arg3)
{
    return sema_init(arg1, arg2, arg3)
}
```

And then conditionally include it with something like

```
#ifdef SOLARIS
#include semaphore_wrappers.h
#endif
```

Note that SOLARIS isn't going to be defined.  You'll either have to manually `#define SOLARIS` when compiling on solaris, or define it in your compile command line / makefile.

At least thats how I'd do it.

Note that if this is ***not*** to be cross-platform compatible, it's much easier to read and debug if you just do a global search and replace.

Comment: Note: linking with `-lpthreads` should solve the problem.  Others have had similar questions elsewhere: http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/programming-scripting/33643-linker-error-undefined-reference-sem_init.html